# if value in input other than defalut div set as visible

Tags: jquery, input, default, onchange

I try to make div visible if value of input other than default. Default value is token from MySQL database.

```
$("input[name='email']").on('keyup',function(){
  if ($("input[name='email']").val() != 'info@example.com')){
      $("div.onchanged").show();
    }else{
      $("div.onchanged").hide();
    }
});
```

Any ideas ?

[JSFIDDLE LINK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ymdBr/)

Comment: Any errors in the console? On a side note, use `this.value != 'info@example.com'`

Comment: What is the error or question?

Comment: if($(this).val() != 'info@example.com'){} is better

Comment: Thank You very much ! Its working now :)
http://jsfiddle.net/ymdBr/1/

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra brace.

```
if ($("input[name='email']").val() != 'info@example.com'){

                                                        ^ here
```

As suggested in the comments, You could have just written `this.value` to avoid the madness around braces:

```
if(this.value != 'info@example.com') {
    //Your code
}
```

*[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ymdBr/3/)*

Comment: No problem but i have low rep... Soon i will :)